# How can i get The Html Object in a Event on Bridge.net C#?

Tags: javascript, c#, addeventlistener, bridge.net

in Bridge.net i can only create a defult eventlistner.
In javascript i will do it like this.

```
<div id="nose" onclick="Test(this);"></div>
<script>
    function Test(htmlelement) {
        var id = htmlelement.id;

        console.log('area element id = ' + id);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

**I fixed that this way.**

```
public Static void SomeFunc(){

                var label = new HTMLLabelElement();
                label.TextContent = txtbox.Value;
                label.Style.FontSize = "40px";
 label.AddEventListener(EventType.Click,ClickEvent );

}

    public static void ClickEvent (Event e)
            {
                var x = (HTMLElement)e.Target;
               x.SetAttribute("value", "HelloWorld");
            }
```

Comment: Here's a [Deck.NET](https://deck.net) sample which demonstrates a similar scenario, see https://deck.net/welcome